# Deleting node in a double linked list is not working

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

This is a  basic function that takes an iterator position and deletes the node in this position but it gives me a runtime error. what am i doing wrong?

```
iterate erase(iterate position)
{
    iterate i;
    Node<T>* temp = head;
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "empty list" << endl;
    }
    else if (position.pointer == head) {
        head = temp->next;
        temp->next->previous = NULL;
        delete position.pointer;
    }
    else {
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (temp == position.pointer->previous) {
                temp->next = position.pointer->next;
                temp->next->previous = temp;
                i.pointer = temp->next;
                delete position.pointer;
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Format your code making it readable.

Comment: Not all paths return a value, which is Undefined Behavior. Also, that while loop will usually never end because you don't update `temp`.

Comment: I fixed the formatting but there is a missing `}`

Comment: For that matter, you don't need a `while` loop at all when dealing with a double-linked list.

Comment: @Nada It seems this while loop while (temp != NULL) is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is lacking adequate `return` statements. There are multiple flows that can cause the function to exit, but only one of them has a `return` statement.  So the return value will largely be *indeterminate*, causing *undefined behavior* for any caller that tries to use the return value.

In any case, your `while` loop iterates forever, because you are not updating `temp` on each iteration of the loop.  You also have a NULL pointer dereference if `position` is pointing at the last node in the list, as you are not checking the new `temp->next` for NULL before accessing `temp->next->previous`.

But, you really don't need the `while` loop *at all*.  The thing about a **double**-linked list is that, given *any* node in the list, you have *direct* access to the nodes that are surrounding it on both sides.  So there is no need to iterate the list hunting for nodes.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
iterate erase(iterate position)
{
    Node<T> *temp = position.pointer;
    if (!temp) return end();

    Node<T> *next = temp->next;
    Node<T> *previous = temp->previous;

    if (next) next->previous = previous;
    if (previous) previous->next = next;
    if (temp == head) head = next;
    //if (temp == tail) tail = previous;
    delete temp;

    iterate i;
    i.pointer = next;
    return i;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
iterate erase(iterate position)
{
    Node<T> *temp = position.pointer;
    if (!temp) return end();

    Node<T> *dummy; // <-- only if no tail ...
    Node<T> **previous = (temp->next) ? &(temp->next->previous) : &dummy/*&tail*/;
    Node<T> **next = (temp->previous) ? &(temp->previous->next) : &head;

    *previous = temp->previous;
    *next = temp->next;
    delete temp;

    iterate i;
    i.pointer = *next;
    return i;
}
```